# Create Telerik RadDataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-store-apps

How can the XAML below coded in C#? I have to create a number of data grids depending on data coming back from a service call. The grids will be displayed side by side horizontally.

```xml
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AlternateRowBackground="CornflowerBlue" GridLinesThickness="3">
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="Some link"></HyperlinkButton>
                        <Button Content="Button"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>

<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid2">
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="CapitalName" Header="Capital Name">
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="gridPrimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                </Style>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>

<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid3">
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="CapitalName" Header="Capital Name">
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="gridPrimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                </Style>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you are trying to solve your problem in the wrong way. Why create multiple RadDataGrid instances which only have 1 column each?

Wouldn't one grid, with multiple columns be a better fit? It would certainly seem so from the data names you've supplied.

Then you can bind the `Visibility` property of each column to some ViewModel property which can show/hide columns according to the data you have available.